# I need to find a way to compare the nth row of data to (n-1)th row or nth row to (n+1)th row in Rapid SQL

Tags: sql, constraints, rapidsql

I need to find a way to compare last row of data to the previous row or the 1st row data to the 2nd row so as to select specific data that have same values in the rows, in Rapid SQL.

My table looks like this..

| ID. |  | ACTION |  | FEEDBACK |  | LANGUAGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112211 |  | AA |  | ERROR |  | ABC |
| 112211 |  | AA |  | ERROR |  | ABC |
| 112211 |  | AB |  | ERROR |  | ABC |
| 112222 |  | AB |  | ERROR |  | ABC |
| 112222 |  | AA |  | ERROR |  | ABC |
| 112222 |  | AB |  | ERROR |  | ABC |

Output should be like:

| ID |  | Action |  | Feedback |  | Language |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112211 |  | AA |  | ERROR |  | ABC |
| 112222 |  | AB |  | ERROR |  | ABC |

Comment: Does Rapid SQL have the concept of ROW_NUMBER() …?

Comment: I am new to this rapid sql, let me check about ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: What is the order of your output? Is it by id and then by action? Ideally you would need a column or combination of columns which uniquely identify any row. Then it can be done with a join (in standard SQL at least it can)

Comment: If you can use row_number() you can get the current row number and minus 1 to get the previous.

Comment: @Skin there's no concept of row_number() in Rapid SQL

Comment: Bugger!  That would've made life easier.